# Background color disappears from safe area when clipShape applied in SwiftUI view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following `SwiftUI` `View`:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()

        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: Constants.horizontalSpacing) {
            VStack(spacing: Constants.verticalSpacing) {
                PaletteBar()
                    .environmentObject(state)

                slider
                    .padding(Constants.sliderInsets)
            }
        }
        .padding(Constants.insets)
        .background(Constants.backgroundColor)
    }
}
```

I used `Spacer` to push the bar down into the safe area and this works well:

[image]

However I need to round the corners of this toolbar using `clipShape`:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()

        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: Constants.horizontalSpacing) {
            VStack(spacing: Constants.verticalSpacing) {
                PaletteBar()
                    .environmentObject(state)

                slider
                    .padding(Constants.sliderInsets)
            }
        }
        .padding(Constants.insets)
        .background(Constants.backgroundColor)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15.0))
    }
}
```

When I apply the clipping this results in the background color no longer displaying in the safe area:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? How can I clip and keep the background color in the safe area?

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question here, not sure if it's the best solution:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()

        ZStack {
            Constants.backgroundColor
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15.0))
                .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)

            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: Constants.horizontalSpacing) {
                VStack(spacing: Constants.verticalSpacing) {
                    PaletteBar()
                        .environmentObject(state)

                    slider
                        .padding(Constants.sliderInsets)
                }
            }
            .padding(Constants.insets)
        }
    }
}
```

Seems `ZStack` is the way to go